# Is it possible to integrate Unity within Lubuntu Desktop Environment?

Tags: unity, lubuntu

Is it possible to integrate Unity Dash in Lubuntu (Fresh Clean Install) apart from installing ubuntu-desktop. If installing ubuntu-desktop is the only option then if installed are there any chances of it breaking the graphic drivers packaging in my system?

Answer (score 2):

No. If you install the Ubuntu Desktop, you will have the choice at log in, of starting a Lubuntu session or a Unity session. I'm afraid you can't run Unity in a Lubuntu session. As for whether your drivers will break or not, will depend on your set-up.

Comment: +1, for the clarification on unity integration with Lubuntu. Under what conditions can graphic drivers on my system break as a result of installing the ubuntu-desktop. The reason I am installing ubuntu-desktop is that I am having issues with everpad.

Comment: Did you follow up at the lubuntu mailing list or with the Launchpad link for your issue with Everpad? You could also ask in the comments section of the blog you linked to in your Everpad question. The author replies to queries. As for your graphics issue, I have no idea but if a Live USB works, you *shouldn't* have a problem. Is this about your [HP laptop](http://askubuntu.com/q/239652/25656)?

Comment: yes I did follow up the launchpad link for the everpad; i also asked for help on the blog; I am yet to get the solution. Yes it is about my HP Laptop.